# Embed Emscripten WebAssembly module in npm package

Tags: npm, webpack, webassembly, emscripten

I'm building an npm package that contains some WebAssembly loaded from Emscripten module "glue code".

For now, the WASM is fetched from the glue code via a static specified URL

```js
// emscripten glue code
import rppgLoader from './set_asm.js';

async load() {
  // load webassembly code
  this.instance = rppgLoader({
  locateFile(path) {
    return `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/wasm/set_asm.wasm`;
  }
});
```

This URL is application-specific and therefore not compatible with an npm module where everything has to be included and compatible with most build systems (webpack, browserify, ...)

I tried following [a gist](https://gist.github.com/surma/b2705b6cca29357ebea1c9e6e15684cc) by google engineer @surma that aims at making wasm/emscripten and webpack work together but got no luck (see last comment on the gist)

What I'm trying to achieve is a npm module transparent for the user. E.g this:

```js
npm install x
import { y } from "x";
```

should work. That include the wasm code and is compatible with most bundlers.

Is this possible? And if so, is there any examples of npm package that made it work ?

Cheers!

Comment: You can use `fs.readFile` to read the file into an `ArrayBuffer` and load a WebAssembly module directly out of it, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I bundled a WASM module into the [`opus-stream-decoder`](https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder) NPM package. [`package.json`](https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder/blob/master/package.json) uses the `main` property to declare the WASM entry point. Also have a look at the [`test-*` files](https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder/tree/master/src) that show import it, using the new ES Modules `import` syntax or the older `require()`

Comment: probably dosn't work in a web page.    the loader will try to find the file based on the URL of the page you are on.

Comment: https://fetch-stream-audio.anthum.com/ uses a Parcel build task to provide the .wasm file alongside the JS bundle. The emscripten loader could possibly be modified to solve [usage from a CDN](https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder/issues/13), but I haven't made time to try unfortunately.

Comment: i just copy the wasm to `scripts/js/`  and it works ok.